# Eigenface approach

Tags: machine-learning, pca

In [principle components analysis (PCA)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) why we need to calculate the eigenface to identify an unknown image? why we do not just use similarity measures to find best match betweem an unknown image and the images in the training data set?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest that you study PCA formally. It is not a difficult algorithm to understand.

PCA is a dimension reduction tool, not a classifier. In Scikit-Learn, all classifiers and estimators have a predict method which PCA does not. You need to fit a classifier on the PCA-transformed data. Scikit-Learn has many classifiers.